# Mysql Fulltext help

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I am using this to search my table:

```
  if ($querystring!=''){$query_cont .= " AND MATCH (headline) AGAINST ('$querystring')"; }
```

Thing is, in the 'headline' field I have a value of say 'BMW'. Then when I enter BMW in the search field, that is "$querystring = 'BMW'", no results are found.

I have set the index of the 'headline' field to 'fulltext', and I insert values to that table with the simple 'INSERT INTO' statement.

Please help me out with this one...

Let me know if you need more input!

Answer (score 3):

Change your `ft_min_word_len` to `3` or less and rebuild your index.

The words shorter than `ft_min_word_len` (which is `4` by default) do not get indexed.

**Update:**

It's considered a good habit to hotlink this obligatory **XKCD** comic to the questions containing the code like yours:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you have to know:

- The minimum amount of characters taken into account is 4, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html if you want to change this
- There is a treshhold for terms appearing more than 50% in the text.

I suspect one of these things is preventing you from getting the results you expect.

Also please make sure your application is protected from [Sql injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL's fulltext indexer ignores three-letter words by default. To get 3-letter words indexed you will need to change the [ft_min_word_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) config and re-index the columns (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584976/how-do-you-get-your-fulltext-boolean-search-to-pick-up-the-term-c) for more; there are also many more stopwords than you might expect).

(You will also need to use mysql_real_escape_string or parameterised queries to stop your above code being an SQL injection vulnerability.)