# Add "dot/period" character as searchable word on mysql innodb fulltext searchs

Tags: mysql, utf-8, foreign-keys, innodb, full-text-search

I have the exact problem as described on [MySQL Match Fulltext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404932/mysql-match-fulltext)

I need to do search with " . " (period) character, i'm using mysql 5.6.4, my table has innodb engine due i need to use some foreigns keys, the field 'fullname' has a fulltext index witg utf8_general_ci collation and it has about 34k+ records, i have in my config ini  `ft_min_word_len = "2" and ft_stopword_file =""` anyway, **it's work perfect with words, the problem is just the *period* character**

so if i tried to search with %like%

```
WHERE  `fullname` LIKE  '%1.9%'
1,061 total, 0.0316 seg

   156 1.9 JTD Impression
    147 1.9 D
    159 1.9 JTS
    GT 1.9 JTD 16V M-Jet Impression
    159 Sportwagon 1.9 JTD
    159 1.9 JTD
```

With match against

```
WHERE MATCH (
fullname
)
AGAINST (
'1.9'
IN BOOLEAN
MODE
)
0 total, 0.0048 seg
```

What can i do? 
Thanks

Comment: We can do full text searches on InnoDB now?

Comment: @Marcus: yeah, it's finaly in the devel pipeline. Not sure which version has it (or of it's still in the labs), but... woo! it is coming. update: http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/12/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-4/

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to find an answer to the same question, and there doesn't seem to be a good way to handle this right now because "." is used as a deliminator. For now I'm replacing "." with "__pd" when inserting a row and when querying the table. Not ideal, but it works for me.